# Exact sequences and Hom

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I have a exact sequence $$1 \longrightarrow A \overset{\phi}\longrightarrow B \overset{\psi}\longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 1$$ of commutative rings $A,B,C$ and the the exact sequence is such that we only consider the multiplicative structure then if I take a free abelian group $X$, how would I form $$0 \longrightarrow Hom(X,A)  \overset{\phi'}\longrightarrow Hom(X,B)  \overset{\psi'}\longrightarrow Hom(X,C)  \longrightarrow 0$$ since in the second sequence the groups are under *addition*. I have seen this done many times when both sequences are of additive groups and you just define $\phi'\circ \alpha=\phi \circ \alpha$ and this works as both $\alpha,\phi$ are additive. But I cant see how to do this when $\phi$ is multiplicative and $\phi'$ has to be additive.

Or more generaly if $A,B,C,X$ where all $G$-modules for some finite group $G$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is: it doesn't matter. These are groups, not rings: *multiplication* and *addition* mean the same thing, i.e. an application of the group operation. And everything's abelian, so talking about *addition* is fine.

Comment: What if $A,B,C$ where rings but in the first exact sequence we had them as groups under multiplication? Ill fix the question as this is what I mean. Sorry

Comment: A ring is a group under multiplication _if and only if_ it is the zero ring. You will have to be much more precise about what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to add to Clive's answer is that, in case $X$ is indeed a *free* Abelian group on $\kappa$ generators, then we have $\hom(X,A)\cong \oplus^\kappa A$. That may make your second exact sequence clearer.